# A mysterious bet

Tags: riddle

> What is a bet that most people take with the intention of losing it?

Comment: "Hey cutie, bet you five bucks you won't go out with me" ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More specifically than TacoV's answer, maybe it's

> life insurance. This could be seen as gambling on your own life, which you always lose in the end (hence *intention* of losing?) but want to keep as long as possible (which could be seen as losing the 'bet' since you're losing money that way).

This specific answer is good because

> not *any* kind of insurance will do: you might either want to get the money or keep the item you're insuring if it's less valuable than your life, depending on context and circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Insurance

Since you'd rather not get the money :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the intended answer, but:

> [Shorting a stock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_(finance)) is when you "bet" that the stock will decline in value.